# How do I get the sum of a SQL rollup statement to the top of the resultset

Tags: sql, rollup

I have a SQL query

```
Select city, sum (tax) 
from db 
group by rollup (city)
```

which is returning:

```
City tax 
A 100
B 300
Null 400
```

So I get the "sum of sums" via rollup.

How can I get the "sum of sums" to the top of the resultset like

```
null 400
A 100
B 300
```

I want to use it in Excel later and don't know the number of lines beforehand.

I tried a subquery, but my database doesn't allow it and I tried
order by

Comment: The two outputs look identical to me.  Did you paste the wrong text above?

Comment: What RDBMS and collation please, the sorting of `NULL` is different for different providers and collation sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you should be specifying the expected sort order, if you do not then the rollup will be appended to the end.

So the first step is to specify that you want to sort by the `city` column in ascending order. But different RDBMS treat `NULL` differently, in your case as judged by the `ROLLUP` syntax, you will need to use the `NULLS FIRST` option to ensure the nulls are processed first in the sort:

```
SELECT city, sum (tax) as tax
FROM db
GROUP BY ROLLUP city ASC NULLS FIRST
```

| city | tax |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 700 |
| C | 300 |
| null | 400 |

> Db fiddle for ORACLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f2ba9694eba76986e4db902e94b9c6d
> **NOTE:** The totals have been changed to illustrate different sort sequeces

In MS SQL Server nulls are treated as the lowest value in any sort, so we don't need any special trickery:
*Notice the different `rollup` syntax*

```
SELECT City, sum (tax) as tax
FROM db
GROUP BY city WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY city
```

| city | tax |
| --- | --- |
| null | 400 |
| A | 100 |
| B | 700 |
| C | 300 |

Things get complicated in MS SQL when you want to have the rollup record displayed first, but sort by an aggregate column. In this case we need to be a little bit more complicated with the sort order:

```
SELECT City, sum (tax) as tax
FROM db
GROUP BY city WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY CASE WHEN city is NUll THEN 1 END DESC, tax desc;
```

| city | tax |
| --- | --- |
| null | 400 |
| B | 700 |
| C | 300 |
| A | 100 |

> See this fiddle for MS SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/?#!18/eb3aa/1

Comment: The complicatedMS SQL magic did solve the problem.

Comment: @Ratilius so what vendor database are you using?

Comment: Frankly I don't know.
 
And +1 for the cool sqlfidle links.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an order by with the nulls first option:

```
Select city, sum (tax) 
from db group by rollup (city) 
order by city asc nulls first
```